# Non blocking read from GNU awk coprocess?

Tags: awk

I would like to implement incremental execution of scripts using `gawk` in order to interleave script source and script output in a document.

The idea would be to read script lines into awk to print them and also pipe them into an appropriate interpreter. Then, on a queue from the input file, read any output from the coprocess and print it to standard output. But it seems that I must know how much output has been generated before looping over the coprocess output.

Is there any way to do a non-blocking read from the coprocess?

```
function script_checkpoint() {
    while(("python3" |& getline output) > 0)
        print output
}

/^# checkpoint/ { script_checkpoint(); next }
{ print; print $0 |& "python3" }
END { script_checkpoint() }
```

EDIT: I have tried to implement this without using a coprocess by buffering the input lines until a checkpoint and just letting the interpreter print to standard out itself but the interpreter always buffers its output until the stream closes. I don't want to close it until the program ends to preserve its internal state.

EDIT: made it more clear that my first intended use case is running python scripts. Here is a sample input/output pair.

```py
print('first line')

# checkpoint

print('second line')
```

should result in

```
print('first line')

first line

print('second line')

second line
```

Comment: From https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html : _It is possible to close just one end of the two-way pipe to a coprocess, by supplying a second argument to the `close()` function of either `"to"` or `"from"`_

Comment: we're missing some details (eg, what is `interpreter`, what does it do, can it be modified, sample inputs and expected outputs) so not sure if this is doable but fwiw ... if `interpreter` can generate a flag (`# checkpoint`) to initiate the call to `script_checkpoint()` ... can `interpreter` be modified to generate an `end-of-checkpoint` flag that `script_checkpoint()` can use to trigger a break from the `while` loop? granted, if `interpreter` fails to generate the `end-of-checkpoint` flag you're back to the same scenario

Comment: Please [edit] your question to come up with a [mcve] we can help you with. For example maybe you want to spawn a process that does `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` (one character at a time, a word at a time, a line at a time or something else?) and read it's output as you go such that given `echo foo | script` you can output `fooFOO` or `fFoOoO` or something else. Or provide some different example that better captures your needs!

Comment: It's not at all clear in what way your current example of outputting `'first line'` given input of `print('first line')` would use a coprocess.

Comment: @markp-fuso I've added an example and made it more clear that `interpreter` will be something like `python3`.

Comment: @EdMorton I want to feed a script line by line into an interpreter (in this case python scripts) in a controlled manner. I thought a co process would be a good way to achieve that control. I feed the script line by line into the interpreter while also printing to stdout and then only collect the script's output at checkpoints (by reading from the other end of the coprocess).

Comment: @EdMorton there was also a typo in my example. The output `print('first line')` is generated by my awk script by just printing its input. The output `first line` is generated by the python interpreter which my awk program prints out at check points (or it should).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general issue:

- `while ((interpreter |& getline output) > 0)` runs until it sees an EOF but ...
- `interpreter` does not end/terminate/exit, thus no EOF is sent so ...
- `awk` hangs while waiting for `interpreter` to send more data so ...
- we end up with a deadlock situation (`awk` waiting for input from `interpreter`; `interpreter` waiting for input from `awk`)

Assumptions:

- need to maintain a single invocation of `interpreter` throughout the run (per a comment from OP); net result: `awk` cannot depend on `interpreter` sending an EOF
- `interpreter` can be modified (to generate additional output)
- the `awk` script has no way of knowing how many lines of output will be generated by `interpreter`

One idea is to setup a handshake between `awk` and `interpreter`.  Within the `while ((interpreter |& getline output) > 0)` loop we'll test for our handshake and when we see it break out of the loop and return back to the main `awk` script.

For demo purposes I'll use a simple `bash` script that does some handshake processing otherwise just prints to stdout whatever it reads from stdin:

```
$ cat interpreter
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    if [[ "${line}" = 'checkpoint' ]]              # received 'checkpoint' handshake?
    then
        echo "CHECKPOINT"                          # send "CHECKPOINT" handshake/acknowledgement
        continue
    else
        echo "interpreter: $line"
    fi
done
```

Demo `awk` code with handshake logic:

```
awk '
function script_checkpoint() {
    while (( cmd |& getline output) > 0) {
          if ( output == "CHECKPOINT" )            # received "CHECKPOINT" handshake/acknowledgement?
             break
          print output
    }
}

BEGIN           { cmd= "./interpreter" }

/^# checkpoint/ { print "checkpoint" |& cmd        # send "checkpoint" handshake
                  script_checkpoint()
                  next
                }

                { print "awk: " $0
                  print $0 |& cmd
                }

END             { print "awk: last checkpoint"     # in case last line of input is not "# checkpoint" we will ...
                  print "checkpoint" |& cmd        # send one last "checkpoint" handshake
                  script_checkpoint()
                  print "awk: done"
                }
' test.dat
```

Sample input file:

```
$ cat test.dat
line1
line2
# checkpoint
line3
line4
# checkpoint
line5
```

Output:

```
awk: line1
awk: line2
interpreter: line1
interpreter: line2
awk: line3
awk: line4
interpreter: line3
interpreter: line4
awk: line5
awk: last checkpoint
interpreter: line5
awk: done
```

**NOTES:**

- `awk` will still hang in the event `interpreter` crashes and/or fails to send back the `CHECKPOINT` handshake
- if the strings `checkpoint` and/or `CHECKPOINT` can show up in the 'normal' data streams then update the code to use strings that are not expected in the data streams

Comment: Very smart. I am not able to modify `interpreter` in my case but I can send it my own auxiliary commands. So in the case of `interpreter==python3`, I can send the command `print("CHECKPOINT")` after the chunk of script input and catch it at the output like you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
BEGIN { cmd="/my/python/script/path" }

function script_checkpoint(      output) {
    close(cmd,"to")
    while ( (cmd |& getline output) > 0 ) {
        print output
    }
    close(cmd)
}

/^# checkpoint/ {
    script_checkpoint()
    next
}
{
    print
    print |& cmd
}

END { script_checkpoint() }
```

Comment: The only thing I would like to avoid here is the `close(cmd)` line. In my case `cmd=="python3"` and I am feeding it chunks of `/my/python/script/path`. So I want to keep `python3` open, preserving its state between checkpoints.

Comment: Are you saying you want to run the python interpreter as some kind of daemon and feed it a line of python code at a time for it to interpret and execute? When you talked about an interpreter in your question I thought you meant something that converts text from one format/language to the other. Anyway, looks like you got an answer so - all the best!

Comment: Yes, that is a good description of what I would like to do: treat the python interpreter as a kind of daemon process. I still haven't quite got it to work but using the hand shake will hopefully help.

Comment: This answer (and a comment on the question) does offer the useful insight that closing the write end of the coprocess with `close(cmd, "to")` may trigger `cmd` to stop reading and start writing output. So a combination of the two answers is likely needed.

Comment: I'm just amazed to hear you can start a python process and send it 1 line at a time for interpretation! You might want to consider using [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) instead of gawk for the other side of that communication.